# Bootstrap div column centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I use Bootstrap 3 and the grid system. I have following HTML to display a sort of navigation.
The problem is my button group cannot be centered. I already tried the built in class "center-block" and different CSS approaches, but failed.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the button group div by applying

```
display:inline-block
```

Then applying to the parent div

```
text-align:center
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/u7g3p/

Answer (score 2):

```
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
```

This will align contents in Bootstrap.
Taken directly from the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `text-akign: center;` to the class `.btn-group`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6159/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class 'text-center' which is bootstrap default class to define text-align:center,
But 'btn-group' class in bootstrap is defined as display:inline-block by default, so width of this div wont be 100% to make your inner links center align.

How to fix -

DOM changes, add class text-center to this div- `<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg text-center">`

CSS changes -

```
.btn-group{
   width:100% (or) display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'text-center' class to the 'btn-group' parent.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively  you can add  tag before and after the div

```
<center>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
```

Here's a modified link :http://jsfiddle.net/sunilkjt/4bq1f320/

Thanks